# Pack a string with an uint34

Tags: ruby, sockets, unix, pack

I'm trying to send something via socket so I made a simple protocol which is :

[Message length (uint32)][Packet id(uint32)][Message]

So, how can I send a message with this protocol ? I tried this :

```
message = 'hi'
parent_socket.send([message.length, 2].pack('LL') + message, 0)
```

and it doesn't seems to work. What I get is just the length and the packet id.
How can I figure this out?

(Updated)
The code I'm using to receive the message is :

```
if child_socket.ready?
  header = child_socket.read(8).unpack('LL')
  length = header[0]
  packet = header[1]
  case packet
    when 1
      stdin.write(child_socket.read(length))
    when 2
      puts child_socket.read(length)
      #send console
    else
      Console.show "Unknown packet : #{packet}"
end
```

The output is 10. Seems normal (4 + 4 + 2)

in that case, length is 2 and packet is 2. So it switch to 'when 2' but it output nothing.

Comment: Your code looks right to construct that format. Can you should the code you are using to receive the message? Also, what is the output of the `child_socket.send` command? (It returns the number of bytes sent.)

Comment: I think I found the problem. Look at my updated post. I think read doesn't remove the bytes from the stream. What should I use instead of read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are only reading the first 8 byes.

```
header = child_socket.read(8).unpack('LL')
```

According to the docs for [IO#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read), if you don't pass a length, it will read to EOF, which should get everything. So just remove that length parameter:

```
header = child_socket.read.unpack('LL')
```

Comment: Did this, now it's blocking on this line. And even if it wouldn't, how would I be able to read the message if I read everything in the header?

Comment: There is a [read_nonblock()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock) method, but I'm not that familiar with it. Seems to be mostly the same, but not blocking -- probably what you need.